# Convert the for loop into stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the below for loop and I need to use collection stream in order to maintain uniformity with other code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < res.getAllLists().size(); i++) {
    if (dataRes.getData().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(
            String.valueOf(res.getAllLists().get(i).getId()))) {
        res.getAllLists().remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A request for code is not taken kindly by this community. The site is intended for questions and answers. Please write the code you need to write, and if you run into any problems, you are welcome to ask a question about your problem.

Comment: By the way, this code doesn't seem to be correct as it is. Whenever you remove an element from the list, the rest of the list gets shifted one space. So if you are at position 3, and delete element 3, what was element 4 will now be element 3. But your `for` loop will not look at it because it is going to move to 4 after the removal.

Comment: There is no need “to maintain uniformity with other code” other than using the interfaces, like the Collection API, which this code already does. But anyway, you can simply use `res.getAllLists().removeIf(obj-> dataRes.getData().getId() .equalsIgnoreCase( String.valueOf(obj.getId())));` though it doesn’t make much sense to do a case insensitive comparison of the string representation of something that seems to be supposed to represent an ID. It would be more reasonable to do `res.getAllLists().removeIf(obj -> dataRes.getData().getId().equals(obj.getId()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to use a `Stream` you can do it like this

```
res.setAllLists(
    res.getAllLists().stream()                          // convert list to stream
        .filter(line -> !dataRes.getData().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(line))     // filter to keep only the non equal items
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));                 // convert back to a list
```

But the Lamda Expression on `List` is a cleaner approach and avoids the performance overhead that introducing `Stream` would do

```
res.getAllLists().removeIf(list -> dataRes.getData().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(list.getId())));
```

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally remove elements from a collection, use the [`removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method.

Note that this does not use Stream processing, as requested in the question, but does use a Lambda Expression, so it is the newer Java 8 "functional" syntax.

```
res.getAllLists().removeIf(list -> dataRes.getData().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                       String.valueOf(list.getId())));
```